# Unable to see site switcher when clicking on the hamburger icon in mobile web

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web

In mobile web, when I click the hamburger icon in the left top corner, instead of opening the site switcher it always redirect to stackexchange.com

So unable to see the site switcher from mobile web.

> [image]

Comment: *sigh* I'm not having a good day with mobile.  Fixing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is building now.

I made an incorrect assumption about the DOM hierarchy around the site switcher, that didn't apply in the mobile topbar.